# Eclipse Project Run problem

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, launching-application

I tried to create a C++ project in Eclipse Helios, it works fine for some simple "Hello World" projects (a single file etc..). However, now I have a little bigger project with several files, the project can still be built without any problems. Actually, when I get into the release folder, the makefile, object files, the actual binary executable are all there. And I could run the binary through the termainl. If I click the "Run/Debug" in Eclipse for this project, it always says "Launch Failed. Binary not found".

How could run the program in Eclipse? I would like to explore its debug features. In addition, I'm running eclipse in CentOS linux and I believe the basic g++, gdb setting etc.. should be all right, otherwise the daemon `hello world` won't work.

Comment: OK, I figure it out myself, but I don't know. It seems you could manually locate the binary's location in the project's Run/Debug Settings. And then, it works

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: I have a very old version of eclipse and the CDT so the current procedure could have changed considerably.*

In the `C/C++ Project` view, expand your project then expand the `Binaries` node. In there you should have a list of the built executables. Right-click on it and select the item `Run As.. > Local C/C++ Application`. This should automatically create a new run configuration which you can access from the green arrow icon and the little bug icon in your tool bar. Click on these to run normally or to run in debug mode.

If you want to tweak how programs are launched, goto to the `Run configuration` menu item of the green arrow icon. Select the configuration that you previously created or make a new one.  You can then tweak the various launch settings like the executable to run, the arguments you want to pass, the required environment variables, etc.

Note that there's also a separate `Debug configuration` that can be accessed from the little bug icon in your toolbar. Within that dialog there's a `Debugger` tab which contains all the controls necessary to set up your debugger. Just [randomly screw around with the controls](http://xkcd.com/627/) until you find something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error, and here is what I did - proper binary parser must be selected so Eclipse can recognize the executable:

**Select the project, then right click.
Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Binary Parsers, PE Windows Parser**

(or you can select Cygwin parser if you use Cygwin compiler, on Linux I use Elf parser).

That worked for me at least for Cross compiler (both on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04)